# Storing salt and key in mysql database table is resulting in an error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Output is as follows:
**WELCOME TO THE LIBRARY SYSTEM
1.LOGIN
2.NEW USER
3.EXIT
Enter your choice : 2
WELCOME, NEW USER, PLEASE ENTER A VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD
Enter username: ASHES
Enter Password: MASON**

And then, there is a traceback of the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
> line 523, in cmd_query
> self._cmysql.query(query,
> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near
> '\xe9\xfbo\xcdrSy\xe9\x9f\xc2\xb7\xebs\x10\x01\xfc\xb6\xa4\xeb\xe6\xe1\xca\xfc\xe'
> at line 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\Downloads\import mysql.connector as sqltor.py", line
> 139, in 
> adduser(username,password)   File "C:\Users\Rotten\Downloads\import mysql.connector as sqltor.py", line
> 71, in adduser
> cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt))   File
> "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py",
> line 269, in execute
> result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,   File "C:\Users\Rotten\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
> line 528, in cmd_query
> raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg, mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> '\xe9\xfbo\xcdrSy\xe9\x9f\xc2\xb7\xebs\x10\x01\xfc\xb6\xa4\xeb\xe6\xe1\xca\xfc\xe'
> at line 1

```
mysql> use library;
Database changed
mysql> desc users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| key      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salt     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

Minimal code:

```
import mysql.connector
import hashlib
import os
mycon=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="123456",database="library")
cursor=mycon.cursor()
stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users'"
cursor.execute(stmt)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result:
    pass
else:
    cursor.execute("create table users(username varchar(20),key varchar(100),salt varchar(100));")
    cursor.execute("create table userlist(username varchar(20),book varchar(200));")
def checkkey(usertest):
    cursor.execute("select count(username) from users where username='{}';".format(usertest))
    count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if count==1:
        return False
    elif count==0:
        return True
    else:
        print("error no valid value returned")
        return False
def adduser(username,password):
    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
    cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt))
    mycon.commit() 
while True:
        print("WELCOME, NEW USER, PLEASE ENTER A VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        usertest=input("Enter username: ")
        usertest2=usertest
        x=checkkey(usertest)
        if x==True:
            password=input("Enter Password: ")
            username=usertest2
            adduser(username,password)
            print("USER CREATED")
            break
        elif x==False:
            print("Username already exists, try again")
            continue
        else:
            print("Error, unknown exception in boolean")
            break
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Pease post everything the question needs in the question - no links to possibly dubious sites..

Comment: pastebin is not a dubious site....? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin.com Its safe, I think :D  Stack was not allowing me to paste the code, for some reason...

Comment: first of all if the user supplies the parameter `username` then this line `cursor.execute("select * from users where username='{}'".format(username))` is dangerous, string formatting does not protect you  from SQL injection AT ALL.

Secondly, could you show us your table schema? and what is `line 523, in cmd_query `  is?

Comment: So, a different variable as username? Sorry, I've only recently started studying python and mysql, so my skills and knowledge isnt exactly, "top notch"...

Comment: "pastebin is not a dubious site"—that's up for discussion. But "dubious" probably isn't the best word here. _All_ critical information must be included _here_, directly in your question. We shouldn't have to go off-site just to understand your question, and we shouldn't have to dig through your "entire code". Help us help you. We're not just here to help _you_, we're here to build a repository of questions and answers that will help others in the future. Links can (and do) break. Please [edit] the relevant code into your question as a [mre]. See [ask].

Comment: desc users;-> https://imgur.com/a/zBsVek0
And.... I am clueless what cmd_query even is.. ._.

Comment: (a) [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).  They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. (b) When hosting images, please only use the official image host. (c) Please put all critical information into your _question_, not a comment.

Comment: please stop linking to external sites. paste your data into the question (yes you can PASTE right into the editor)

Comment: oh oke, gotcha, im still pretty new to this, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes...

Comment: So, if i wanted to add things, I have to edit the inital question and its body to include that?

Comment: correct.  also, looking at your error message i think i see the problem `in adduser cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt)) ` notice that you do `values('{}','{}','{}'` there doesn't appear to be a closing brace, please double check that

Comment: add  `, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8"` to your connection string,

Comment: Just edited the post, and also, did what Nullman and nbk asked, but nope, there's still an error...

Comment: is it the SAME error? if not add it to the question and please add the code for `adduser` method or which ever method your exception is happening in

Comment: Yup, exact same error, only difference being the salt and key codes. Everything else, identical match.

Comment: you still didn't fix this `"insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'"` it needs to be `"insert into users values('{}','{}','{}')"` (notice the closing `)` )

Comment: you also appear to be trying to insert `bytes` into `varchar` fields which im not sure is supported in mysql

Comment: Like i said, im still new to coding, and I have no clue how to do/fix that....Looking through the internet is not helping much either...

Comment: first of all add the closing brace and see what error you get, then if it still doesnt work, try either changing your table fields that you try to push bytes into (like salt) to `binary` or `varbinary` in mysql

Comment: Sorry for the late response, had to completely reinstall mysql because I couldnt alter or drop tables, and yes, same error, even after changing the datatype(do I change the datatype entry in the question to the newer one too?)

Comment: ok so we're back to this line `cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt))` the problem lies in you trying to format bytes into strings which doesn't always work and you shouldnt use string formatting to fill statements anyway. try:     `cursor.execute("insert into users values(%s, %s, %s)", (username,key,salt))`  and make sure you do @name when talking to someone or they wont know you replied (in my case use @Nullman)

Comment: it works, IT FINALLY WORKS @Nullman thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness sake here is the full answer:

there are several issues:

1. unbalanced parenthesis on this line `cursor.execute("insert into users values('{}','{}','{}'".format(username,key,salt))`
2. trying to insert byte data into `varchar` - this MAY work, it really depends on your sql engine
3. using string formatting for binary data

the solution to 1. and 3. is to use prepared statements:

```
cursor.execute("insert into users values(%s, %s, %s)", (username,key,salt))
```

If the issue persists then change the appropriate data types in your table from `varchar` to something like `binary` or `varbinary`